# CSS code for a table in Squarespace?

Tags: css-tables, squarespace

I'm looking for CSS code on creating a solid colored table with an image and text wrap. This is to be used in Squarespace. Anyone know how I can get that?

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            .mycss {
                background-color: #997E6E;
                border: 21px solid #997E6E;
                color: #FFFFFF;
                font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
                font-size: 15px;
                font-weight:normal;
                letter-spacing: 1pt;
                line-height:1;
                word-spacing: 2pt;
                text-align: left;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p class="mycss">
            As my teacher says, our bodies are the best technology we have! Through it, we can transform ourselves from being blocked and out of balance into being energetic, clear-minded and open-hearted.
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing this outside of the developer  platform...

I would put the class inside a div instead of p

```
<div class="mycss">
    <p> As my teacher says, our bodies are the best technology we have! Through it, we can transform ourselves from being blocked and out of balance into being energetic, clear-minded and open-hearted.</p>
</div>
```

Your css looks fine for the border. If you want to float the image to the right inside this div, add

```
.mycss img { 
float:right;
}
```